# Copying to Postgres in while loop

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

Having somewhat a strange issue with python, not unsure if this is something to do with psycopg2 or some rookie error im making with python.

Essentially i have a function that copy's data from a csv and attempts to insert it into a pgsql database using psycopg2. If there is an a data type error i want the code to try and rectify it and then re-attempt to insert the data into the data base. here is the code:

```
def copy(self, csvFile):
    error = True
    i = 0
    while error:
        try:
            i += 1
            print(f'attempt {i}')
            self.connect()
            csr = self.conn.cursor()
            csr.copy_expert("COPY foo.bar FROM STDOUT NULL '' CSV HEADER", csvFile)
        except psycopg2.DataError as err:
            print(err)
            print(err.pgcode)
            csr.close()
            self.conn.close()
            #self.conn.rollback()
            if err.pgcode == '22001':
                if 'character varying' in err.args[0]:
                    currlength = re.search(r'\((.*?)\)', err.args[0]).group(1)
                    newlength = int(currlength) * 2
                    s = err.args[0].split()
                    col = s[s.index('column') + 1].replace(':','')
                    sql = f'alter table foo.bar alter column {col} type varchar({newlength})'
                    print(f'Column Length too short adjusting {col} from {currlength} to {newlength}\n {sql}')
                    self.execute(sql)
            elif err.pgcode == '22p02':
                s = err.args[0].split()
                col = s[s.index('column') + 1].replace(':', '')
                sql = f'alter table foo.bar alter column {col} varchar(64)'
                print(f'numeric column {col} contains text altering to varchar')
                self.execute(sql)
        else:
            self.conn.commit()
            csr.close()
            error = False
```

What happens is that the first try executes as expected and throws the error, then the alter table statement runs correctly, on the second attempt the copy_expert function does nothing but doesnt error and the code completes without inserting the csv data into the database. This is the output showing it tries for the second time.

```
> attempt 1 
> value too long for type character varying(1) CONTEXT:  COPY
table, line 3, column id: "12345678"
> 
> 22001 
> Column Length too short adjusting assetid from 1 to 2  
> alter table foo.bar alter column id type varchar(2) 
> Executing query alter table foo.bar alter column assetid type varchar(2)             
> attempt 2
> Download and insert of file.csv Complete
```

Comment: `COPY foo.bar FROM STDOUT [...]`: shouldn't that read `COPY foo.bar FROM STDIN [...]`?

Comment: its a good point @shmee but its not the problem. if the table doesn't need alteration. i.e. the exception isn't reached the data copy's to the database no problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, after having spent ~30 minutes enthusiastically walking down a blind alley, I think I found the cause of the issue. It has neither to do with `psycopg2`, nor would I necessarily call it a rookie mistake. I was actually quite convinced that it was about isolation levels ... it wasn't.

It's the file handle. The file is read completely by `copy_expert` so the internal pointer is at its end when the `psycopg2.DataError` raises. There's simply nothing left to read from that handle the second time around.

If you put `csvFile.seek(0)` in your `except` block, the pointer will be reset to the beginning of the file.

```
except psycopg2.DataError as err:
    csvFile.seek(0)
```

I have created a little test class using your `copy` method and implemented the methods `execute` and `connect` the way I assumed you did. 
I was able to reproduce the behavior you describe in your post and resetting the pointer in the `except` block led to the data in the file being visible in the database after the second attempt, following the modification of the column length.

Comment: Excellent. Interesting i was starting to assume that nothing was actually wrong with the code and that its was reading nothing, which i guess i kind of true. I have never actually seen the seek method within csv, but anyway cant thank you enough works a treat now

Comment: @Tik [`seek`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.TextIOBase.seek) is a method of `TextIOBase` objects. An instance of a subclass of these is returned by `open()` when passing the path to a file to it.